# App won't run when interface is added to class definition but dll is missing

Tags: c#, interface

I'm new to the forum and not a professional programmer, so apologies if I am not using the correct terminology.

I am using a 3rd party DLL in my c# forms application, and it has an interface which (in their example) I specify when creating the class:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form, PIEHid32Net.PIEDataHandler, PIEHid32Net.PIEErrorHandler
```

The problem is that the dll, which is added to my project as a reference, may not exist.  If it does not exist, the application doesn't start (and in Visual Studio I get a `FileNotFoundException` as soon as I step into the code, before I could add a `try`/`catch` etc.

I can create the DLL from the installer which works fine, but historically I have also added it to the app as an embedded resource and exported it at runtime if it did not exist - which is nice if someone just copies the exe rather than doing a full install.  But I've never had a DLL with an "interface" defined in the above way.  I guess because the class is referencing it, the app will never run.

So is there a way around this?  A way to add the interface reference as being "optional", or adding it at runtime AFTER I have exported the DLL to which they reference?

Comment: Why can't you simply bundle the dll with your application? If you have added the reference and used it the JITter needs it when encountering the type that used it.

Comment: I can, and do.  But if someone copies only the exe itself to another folder / another machine, the dll won't be there any more.  As I said, I embed it as a resource that I export, but I don't get as far as being able to do that because of the interface reference.  It works for every other dll I have used, because they are only referenced within the form that I run, AFTER I have exported the dll in Main()

Comment: @Chris Then you are trying to fix an end-user's unwanted behavior by possibly a wrong approach. Provide them with an installer and they won't have the ambition to *copy the exe only*.

Comment: Again, there is an installer, and I also have this workaround in place for users that copy the exe only, which works in every respect except this one.  I'm not asking if it is the "correct" thing to do in an ideal world, just whether it is possible and if so, how.  It solves a problem that otherwise causes a support phone call, or bad experience for the user (they may just decide it doesn't work and go elsewhere).  I can't even pop up a messagebox telling them they have been stupid currently, as I can't catch the error.

Comment: For reference, the usual cause of an end user copying the exe is that they want a second instance running on the same machine, with different settings.  There is a correct way to do this within the app, but I've had more than a dozen people do it the incorrect way.  So it is a real problem that I have no control over.  I became bored of the emails complaining it didn't work, so I started exporting the required DLLs as a fallback if the installer hadn't been run.

Comment: If you want to solve this problem you need to bundle the dll into your executable so that you can put it back on disk **or** resolve it, you can take over assembly resolution if you want. However, as noted by others, this is simply wrongful behavior of your users if they do this. In 2017 nobody expects a single executable to work if you yank it out of a folder full of other files.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do :-(  Or have I misunderstood "bundle"?  I have added it as a resource and have code to export it to disk - but I can't execute that code because the 'FileNotoundException' happens before any code gets executed - because of the interface reference in the class definition.